Radiation reaction in the ground state of an atom
In a typical bound energy eigenstate of an atom the magnitude of the wave function is time independent only phase changes in time. So I expect no radiation reaction force in the ground state. However I saw in literature(1,2) that in Heisenberg picture the radiation reaction  in the ground state related to  the second time derivative of position operator has finite value and therefore there is radiation reaction so that only vacuum fluctuations may prevent further loss of energy. I cannot understand how there can be finite second time derivative of position operator in a stationary bound state with zero angular momentum (s orbital)
1.Role of the electromagnetic vacuum in the transition from classical to quantum mechanics byAna María Cetto and Luis de la Peña
March 23, 2022
https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.11393 (subsection 3.4)
2."quantum vacuum"(book) by peter milonni. Page 144. End of Subsection 4.13

Please do not delete and repost questions. Original question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/817773/174766

I added the requested links
